# Object in array that exists returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, dom

I have an array from `document.getElementsByClassName` which has 8 elements, but whenever i want to access one the console returns undefined.

`console.log(array)` returns all objects from 0 - 7

`console.log(array[0])` returns undefined

how is this even possible? thanks for any help!

`console.log(array)`:

```
HTMLCollection
​
0: <li class="all-products-item" data-v-3d846c36="" data-spider-action-name="h5店铺首页-全部-综合" style="color: rgb(230, 36, 36);">
​
1: <li class="all-products-item" data-v-3d846c36="" data-spider-action-name="h5店铺首页-全部-分类" style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34);">
​
2: <li class="all-products-item" data-v-3d846c36="" data-spider-action-name="h5店铺首页-全部-销量" style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34);">
​
3: <li class="all-products-item price" data-v-3d846c36="" data-spider-action-name="h5店铺首页-全部-价格" style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34);">
​
4: <li class="all-products-item" data-v-3d846c36="" data-spider-action-name="h5店铺首页-全部-综合" style="color: rgb(230, 36, 36);">
​
5: <li class="all-products-item" data-v-3d846c36="" data-spider-action-name="h5店铺首页-全部-分类" style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34);">
​
6: <li class="all-products-item" data-v-3d846c36="" data-spider-action-name="h5店铺首页-全部-销量" style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34);">
​
7: <li class="all-products-item price" data-v-3d846c36="" data-spider-action-name="h5店铺首页-全部-价格" style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34);">
​
length: 8
​
<prototype>: HTMLCollectionPrototype { item: item(), namedItem: namedItem(), length: Getter, … }
```

Comment: This appears to be from your console.  If you can, please copy the pertinent script and markup into the comment block so we can better help you out.  Also, read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Comment: That's not an array, it's an `HTMLCollection`. `getElementsByClassName()` returns a "live" NodeList. So if you change the classes of the elements, the collection changes.

Comment: Or if you add/remove elements from the DOM, the collection changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a live [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of found elements; thus, if the DOM is changed and some of those elements are removed or have some of their classes removed, the change will also be reflected in the `HTMLCollection`. If you only want a static collection of elements with certain classes at a particular time, you can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). In your case, you can use:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".all-products-item");
```